# Perplexing non-trailing parameter pack behaviour

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer

I've come across some interesting variadic template function behaviour. Can anyone point out the relevant rules in the standard which define this?

[GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06e1785c5396a168), [ICC](https://godbolt.org/g/ChOnjW) and [MSVC](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) compile the following code successfully (Clang doesn't, but I understand that this is due to compiler bugs).

```
template<class A, class... Bs, class C>
void foo(A, Bs..., C) { }

int main()
{
    foo<int, int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

In this call to `foo`, template arguments are provided for `A` and `Bs`, then `C` is deduced to be `int`.

However, if we simply flip the last two template parameters:

```
template<class A, class C, class... Bs>
void foo(A, Bs..., C) { }
```

Then [all](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f7a73a493e7220ba) [three](https://godbolt.org/g/PWAEb6) [compilers](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) throw errors. Here is the one from GCC:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:8:42: error: no matching function for call to 'foo(int, int, int, int, int)'
     foo<int, int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
                                          ^
main.cpp:4:6: note: candidate: template<class A, class C, class ... Bs> void foo(A, Bs ..., C)
 void foo(A, Bs..., C) { }
      ^~~
main.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:8:42: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 5 provided
     foo<int, int, int, int>(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
                                      ^
```

To make things more interesting, calling with only four arguments is [invalid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecf9154da05ce210) for the first `foo`, and [valid](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8be017606e20f5c2) for the second.

It seems that in the first version of `foo`, `C` *must* be deduced, whereas in the second, `C` *must* be explicitly supplied.

What rules in the standard define this behaviour?

Comment: I would say that the first example, the one that compiles, should not be. It's ill-formed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can you explain why?

Comment: The template is explicitly instantiated with four parameters. The template expands the same parameters as parameters to the function call. The function call is expected to take four parameters. Passing five actual parameters to a function call that expects four parameters is ill-formed.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The interpretation taken by those three compilers takes the four template arguments as `A` (`int`), and `Bs` (`{int,int,int}`), then `C` is deduced, so it *is* a function expecting five parameters by that logic. I don't know whether that's the correct logic though.

Comment: That's a fair point. So, it looks like when a parameter pack ends the template declaration, the compiler expects an explicit template parameter list to initialize the entire parameter pack, without any additional parameter deduction.

Comment: I would doubt first example is compliant without further research.  Do you have evidence you can supply?

Comment: @Yakk Unfortunately I have little other than second-hand assurances; see [this](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2105) CWG issue and Johannes Schaub's comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38629601/function-template-parameter-pack-not-at-the-end-of-the-parameter-list/38629697#38629697). If it were just a single compiler acting this way then I would be more suspicious.

Comment: @Yakk I believe that this is okay because the pack is in a non-deduced context, so the last argument is used to deduce the type of the final template parameter.

Comment: @tartan except how does the compiler know you are completely defining the pack and not just the prefix?

Comment: @Yakk Because any further function arguments you pass can't be deduced for the pack, so there's no other way to specify the arguments, so you must be completely defining it. (if I understand your question correctly)

Comment: See also [this defect](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1399).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is often the case, the answer came to me a few hours after I posted the question.

Consider the two versions of `foo`:

```
template<class A, class... Bs, class C>
void foo1(A, Bs..., C) { }

template<class A, class C, class... Bs>
void foo2(A, Bs..., C) { }
```

and the following call (assuming `foo` is `foo1` or `foo2`):

```
foo<int,int,int,int>(1,2,3,4,5);
```

In the case of `foo1`, the template parameters are picked as follows:

```
A = int (explicitly provided)
Bs = {int,int,int} (explicitly provided)
C = int (deduced)
```

But in the case of `foo2` they look like this:

```
A = int (explicitly provided)
C = int (explicitly provided)
Bs = {int,int} (explicitly provided)
```

`Bs` is in a non-deduced context (`[temp.deduct.type]/5.7`), so any further function arguments can not be used to extend the pack. As such, `foo2` must have all it's template arguments explicitly provided.

Comment: Long story short: don't mess with non-trailing variadic template packs. Unless you know what you're doing. Which is a valid statement for everything C++.